# Spring security with only one user

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm making a web app with spring security and I would like it to be accessible by only one user, with his login and password stored in code or xml.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use InMemoryAuthentication. So u dont need a Database:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("pw123").roles("ADMIN");
          auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1").password("pw123").roles("USER");
          auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user2").password("pw123").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Instead of defining the user and password in code you can read them from your XML-file.

Comment: Also if you are storing these credentials in an external property file, you can use `org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource` annotation and `org.springframework.core.env.Environment` object in above configuration class.